# Alexa announce a response without extra Intent request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am implementing a custom alexa skill that having a request which is used to post a message (eg: Bring account files) on slack chat.The user who receives the order and responding after skill closed.Is there  any way to announce the user's reply (eg: will bring in 10 minutes) through alexa device without any extra intent request.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is however, a much requested feature. So I recommend you vote for it here:

https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/32555959-enable-and-allow-true-push-capabilities